# Laravel 4: selection many to many relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many

I work on a blog project, which have relation many to many between "posts" and "cats" tables (with pivote table)

```
posts:
    id
    title
    topic

cats:
    id
    name

cat_post:
    post_id
    cat_id
```

I prepare models correctly,
so, how to select all posts in specific category? I tried:

```
Cat::with('post')->where('id', '=', '3')->get();
```

and

```
Post::with('cat')->whereId('3')->get();
```

but nothing yet,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better/shorter:

```
$cats = Cat::with('post')->find(3);
```

**Update:**

```
$cats = Cat::with(array('post' => function($q) { // make sure posts not post
    $q->orderBy('id', 'desc'); // order the posts
}))->find(3); // No need to order a single model
```

Answer (score 0):

just found the answer

```
$cats = Cat::with('post')->whereId(3)->first();
```

then retrive it in blade:

```
@foreach($cats->post as $post)
    {{$post->title}}
@endforeach
```

thanks,

Comment: Check my answer, it's shorter.